# Using wordpress as a CMS and localization service

Tags: wordpress, localization, wordpress-rest-api

We're building multiple single page apps that all consume the same service based API. One of our requirements is to offer a simple CMS that allows an admin to create marketing pages.

I was able to set up a wordpress instance using the multisite plugin and put it behind our own API. This allows us to use wordpress as a CMS service. We can create pages in the wordpress admin area and then pull the content in using the wordpress rest api plugin.

One of the problems I'm having is to migrate our key, value translation string files into wordpress. We'd like to store them in the database and use wordpress as a place to edit them and then query for them using the rest api plugin. Our translation files are json format and look like this:

`{
  "LOGIN_LABEL": "Sign In",
  "LOGOUT_LABEL": "Sign Out",
  "SIGN_UP_LABEL": "Register"
}`

Looking for any solutions that would help us use wordpress as a place to store key value pairs, edit them, and do GET requests to pull them in.

Comment: If you have a php developer, you can use the WordPress JSON API or JSON Rest API. You can store the values in the WordPress DB, set up authentication, etc